# Xamarin Android - Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When pressing the login button, it throws an error mentioned despite the async is already used in the button to run the task and the code is correct.

```
token = await Task.Run(() => { return core.SignIn(username.Text, password.Text); }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Something in your function is making UI changes from a thread other than main.  That isn't allowed in Android.  Solution is to do those changes on the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to interact with an element of the UI that was created by the primary dispatcher from within a Task.

```
token = await Task.Run(() => 
{ 
    return core.SignIn(username.Text, password.Text); 
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

needs to be something like:

```
token = await Task.Run(() => 
{ 
    Activity.RunOnUiThread(()=>{
        return core.SignIn(username.Text, password.Text); 
    });
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**EDIT:**

Slight tweak based on the assumption that you're getting the username and password from EditText controls:

```
token = await Task.Run(() => 
{ 
    string usernm = string.Empty;
    string pass = string.Empty;

    Activity.RunOnUiThread(()=>{
          usernm = username.Text;
          pass = password.Text;
    });

    return core.SignIn(usernm, pass);
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value (return) on the code you mentioned.

Comment: it's your code, all I did was wrap the primary operation in a main dispatcher delegate. Have you actually tried it?